# Custom UINavigationBar background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, background-color

[image]

Here is a `UINavigationController`, with a custom `UINavigationBar` *(I add its height to extra 12px)*

**CustomNavigationBar**

```
- (void)initialize
{
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -12)];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    return CGSizeMake(320, 44 + 12);
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *classNamesToReposition = @[@"_UINavigationBarBackground"];

    for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {

        if ([classNamesToReposition containsObject:NSStringFromClass([view class])]) {

            CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
            CGRect frame = [view frame];
            frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + 12;
            // hack for iOS 6
            if (IOS7_ABOVE) frame.origin.y -= 20.0f;
            frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + 20.f;

            [view setFrame:frame];
        }
    }
}
```

In the second `viewController`, I hide the `navigationBar` in `viewWillappear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // without this line, the bottom part will be black color
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = barBackgroundColor;

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:barBackgroundColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    ...
}
```

My question here is why I set the same backgroundColor as `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:barBackgroundColor];` but it shows a different color, and some more there is a shadow between the 2 colors.

What is the problem here? any solution for this?

Comment: Where is the line that shows your [UINavigationBar appearance] ?

Comment: @ElTomato in `AppDelegate.m` `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: WHERE DO WE SEE YOUR [UINavigationBar appearance]?

Comment: I update to the question, please see the last section